# I want to concatenate the result of these these two select queries as four columns in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

```
select 
    SUM (cp.TotalAmount) as totalPaymentamount,
    lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountName as account1
from 
    TBLCPVMaster cp,TBLLevel4 lvl4
where 
    cp.SubSubsidaryAccountId = lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountCode  
group by 
    lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountName

select 
    SUM (cr.TotalAmount) as totalReciveamount,
    lvl4_2.SubSubsidaryAccountName as account2
from 
    TBLCRVMaster cr, TBLLevel4 lvl4_2
where 
    cr.SubSubsidaryAccountId = lvl4_2.SubSubsidaryAccountCode 
group by 
    lvl4_2.SubSubsidaryAccountName
```

The resultant table should have 4 columns...please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question? All I see are two SQL statements and an expected result.

Comment: these are two differnt quries and gives result as two differnt tables with two columns each table .. i want to join all the columns together of these two tables

Comment: please add that to your question rather than just placing it here in the comments where it may be missed.

Comment: now you know ! kindly please give me an answer :D

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should start using the join syntax from ANSI-92. It has been 25 years.

```
with Payments as
(
    select SUM (cp.TotalAmount) as totalPaymentamount
        ,   lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountName as account1
    from TBLCPVMaster cp
    join TBLLevel4 lvl4 on cp.SubSubsidaryAccountId = lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountCode 
    group by lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountName
)
, Receipts as
(
    select SUM (cr.TotalAmount) as totalReciveamount
        , lvl4_2.SubSubsidaryAccountName as account2
    from TBLCRVMaster cr
    join TBLLevel4 lvl4_2 on cr.SubSubsidaryAccountId = lvl4_2.SubSubsidaryAccountCode 
    group by lvl4_2.SubSubsidaryAccountName 
)

select p.totalPaymentAmount
    , p.account1
    , r.totalReciveAmount
    , r.account2
from Payments p
cross join Receipts r
```

Comment: thank you for your answer .. but it says invalid column names

Comment: You have to give the subquery an alias for it to work. I edited my response above.

Comment: still not working :( totalreciveamount and account 2 invalid column names :(

Comment: Oh good grief. The original code I posted isn't going to do what you want. You need to get the two resultsets differently. Here is one way to do it.

Comment: actually i am beginner in writing sql quries  and these joins really sucks :( and still its not working :D

Comment: you answer gives me  the desired result but with repeating rows .... i.e. the CPVMASTER table contains 6 rows but it returns me 18 rows ..it doesn't group up the account names!!

Comment: Well...I have nothing to test this with. I am coding in the dark here. Please provide the ddl and sample data. sqlfiddle.com would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Im just taking the simplest understanding of what I think you are trying to achieve... get the total paid and total received for each account.

```
select 
    lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountName, -- surely you only need name once?
    SUM (cp.TotalAmount) as totalPaymentamount,
    SUM (cr.TotalAmount) as totalReciveamount
from 
    TBLLevel4 lvl4
    left join TBLCPVMaster cp 
        on cp.SubSubsidaryAccountId=lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountCode
    left join TBLCRVMaster cr
        on cr.SubSubsidaryAccountId=lvl4_2.SubSubsidaryAccountCode
group by lvl4.SubSubsidaryAccountName
```

Comment: thank you for your rply ,,, according to this way it only gets the two same accounts in both tables and does not display the differnt accounts

Comment: If I understand your comment you want all accounts whether they have had payments or not, try the above with the edits I have made.

Comment: thanks again man!! u get my point.. i have to create a report of receipt and payment accounts that's why i need two queries with two account names to display seprately receipt account as well as payment account